# Properties of a Set Consisting of a Single Point

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

> If a set $S$ consists of a single point $\{p\}$ in the complex plane $(\mathbb{R^2})$, then is $p$ an interior point, an exterior point, or a boundary point? Is $S$ open, closed, connected, compact, or a region?

Looking closely at the definitions, I believe $p$ is a boundary point as $\forall\epsilon>0, \ B(p,\epsilon)$ contains both points in $S$ and not in $S$.

If this is true, then $S$ must be closed, as $S$ contains all of its boundary points. It is also compact as $S$ is bounded and closed. I don't think it can be connected as no two points can be connected by a polygonal path that lies entirely in $S$ ($S$ consists of only a single point anyway). It also can't be a region as $S$ is not open.

Is this correct?

**EDIT**:

The set $S=\{p\}$ consists of a single point in the complex plane. Let's consider the set $S^C=\{\mathbb{C}$\ $p$}. Now take an arbitary point $q\in S^c$. The distance  from $q$ to $p$ is $|p-q|=\delta$ for some $\delta>0$. Now consider the ball $B\left(q,\frac{\delta}{2}\right)$. Clearly $B\left(q,\frac{\delta}{2}\right)\cap S^C=B\left(q,\frac{\delta}{2}\right)$. Hence $q$ is an interior point. So $S^c$ is open$\Rightarrow S$ is closed.

$S$ is connected is vacuously true. $S$ is also compact as it's closed and bounded. $S$ is not a region (unsure of reason, but it intuitively makes sense).

Comment: How do you know $S$ contains _all_ of its boundary points?

Comment: Since there are not even two distinct points in $S$ to check in the definition of connectedness, it is [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) connected.

Comment: How do you know there aren't boundary points of $S$ besides $p$?

Comment: @eric wofsey Ah crap, I overlooked this. Is it vacuously closed?

Comment: @Bell Consider any point $q$ different from $p$ and check if $q$ can be a boundary point. If you can find a neighborhood (ball) of $q$ that excludes $p$, then it is not a boundary point; otherwise it is.

Comment: Where is your singleton set? A singleton set in a metric space can be open.

Comment: Did you even say that it is a metric space?

Comment: @angryavian I see. So by that argument, $S$ does contain all of it's boundary points as $\exists q\in S^c$ s.t. $\exists\epsilon>0$ s.t. $B(q,\epsilon)\cap S=\emptyset$

Comment: This question is exactly copied. Interpret it as you will.

Comment: If that is the question then you have failed to provide the necessary context.  Is $S$ assumed to be contained in a metric space?  Is it Euclidean space?  Or are we considering the topology on $S$ itself?

Comment: I shall ask my lecturer tomorrow. I agree that there are missing, essential details. But I assume as this is a course in complex analysis, that $p$ is some point in the complex plane. Does that help?

Comment: As a side note, the statement "it cannot be a region since it's not open" refers to the openness of the set, which you did not determine yet. It almost looks like you assumed that it is not open since it's closed, which is absolutely not the case in a general topology (in fact, if we're considering the topology on the set itself, it is both open and closed). This only adds to the other observations about the fact that better context is necessary.

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope this helps.